# An uncountable Baire γ-space without an isolated point exists?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, selection-principles

An open cover $U$ of a space $X$ is:

• an $\omega$-cover if $X$ does not belong to $U$ and every finite subset of $X$ is contained in a member of $U$.

• a $\gamma$-cover if it is infinite and each $x\in X$ belongs to all but finitely many elements of $U$.

Recall that $X$ has the property $\gamma$ ($X$ is a $\gamma$-space): for any open $\omega$-cover $\alpha$ of $X$ there is a sequence $\beta\subseteq \alpha$ such that $\beta$ is a $\gamma$-cover of $X$.

A topological space $X$ is Baire if the intersection of any sequence of open dense subsets of $X$ is dense in $X$.  Any Cech-complete space is Baire.

It is well known that if $X$ is a Cech-complete $\gamma$-space then $X$ contains an isolated point
(see Theorem 4 in [J. Gerlits, Zs. Nagy, Some properties of C(X), I, Topology Appl., 14 (1982), pp. 151-161]).

**Question**. Let $X$ be an uncountable Baire $\gamma$-space (+$X$ is perfectly normal).
Then $X$ contains an isolated point ?